# creating an event driven macro for a dynamically created combo box(OLEObject)

Tags: vba, excel

how to create an event driven macro for a dynamically created combo box?(OLEObject) I was able to create macros dynamically for buttons of the same sort but was unable to do it for combo box.
Thanks

This is the code for combo box creation

```
Dim lcbxObj As OLEObject
Set lcbxObj = .OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", _
Link:=False, _
DisplayAsIcon:=False, _
Left:=0, _
Top:=lintTop, _
Width:=189, _
Height:=20)
```

Comment: What do you want to assign? A macro for a click event? How do you create the combo box? (and: please just one question)

Comment: yes exactly.for click event